# How to sync two models representing the same object but with a different cid?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational, marionette

In my app, user can create vehicles. On the "show specific vehicle" page, I have an instance of Vehicle (which extend RelationalModel from [Backbone Relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/)). When I change the avatar of the vehicle, this model is changed.

In another page "show vehicles list" of the application, I have a gallery showing the vehicles of the user. The models (instances of Vehicle too) are in a collection. Unfortunately, they have a different CID and thus are not updated properly when the user changes the avatar of the Vehicle in the show Page.

How to deal with that? I would like the Vehicle #9 to be the same everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

I would define an application-level vehicleCollection (A) where you store all vehicles you get from every single request that returns vehicles (B, C). Since every vehicleId will be the same, you can do a look-up in the main collection (A) if the model already exists when you loop over the resultset from the other collection fetch (B, C).

You will most likely need to work with temporary collections and inject the relevant model from the main collection (A)

If you look through the tests that come with the Backbone package (or just go to their github repo) you can clearly see how it works adding the same model to different collections

Comment: +1 I typically do this with modules. I'll have 1 module that deals with the model/collection and related features, and then other modules will call in to that one to get the models when they need to.

Comment: +1 here too, one common Collection in charge of be synchronized with the server and sub-Collections that feeds from the common one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't forget you, I'm just working on something else at the moment. I'm likely to try it next week.